# How to share source code between ver2010 and ver2013

Tags: development, migration

Following this good article:
[how-to-migrate-a-sharepoint-2010-solution-to-a-2013](http://www.threewill.com/how-to-migrate-a-sharepoint-2010-solution-to-a-2013/)
I migrated a project from:

Sharepoint 2010 + Visual Studio 2012 + .NET 3.5
to

Sharepoint 2013 + Visual Studio 2013 + .NET 4.5

Now I would like to share as much as possible the source code.
Using conditional compilation I managed with .cs files, for example:

```
string myPath = @"~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/" +
#if COMPAT_SP2013 
@"15/" +
#endif
@"mypath/";
```

but I can't use the same method for .aspx and .ascx files where I have to resolve just few differences on the header. An example:

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls"     Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="InputFormSection" Src="~/_controltemplates/15/InputFormSection.ascx" %>
```

instead of

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="InputFormSection" Src="~/_controltemplates/InputFormSection.ascx" %>
```